# Jquery JSON object is not saving with localStorage in a .append located in a .prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I'm pretty new to JS/Jquery, and this is an interesting issue. Although I'm not too sure what the issue is.

I'm making a notes app to familiarize myself with Jquery, and I have the notes being saved as JSON objects in localStorage. Every note has an ID (the date), the top pixels, the left pixels, the content, and the title.

To make the notes, I just have a chain of .append and .prepend. The '.append' which contains my contentEditable (i know, i know, I shouldn't use it) doesn't save when placed in my '.prepend' block (which contains the sticky headers).

[image: example]

The title -does- save when I move it below the .prepend block [image: example2]

Here is the version that is placed correctly but doesn't save:

```
        data = data || { id : +new Date(), top : "40px", left : "40px", text : "Note Here", title : "Title" }
    return $("<div />", { 
        "class" : "sticky",
        'id' : data.id
    })

    .prepend($("<div />", { "class" : "sticky-header"} )

        .append($("<span />", { 
            "class" : "sticky-status", 
            click : saveSticky 
        }))
        .append($("<span />", { 
            "class" : "close-sticky", 
            text : "trash", 
            click : function () { deleteSticky($(this).parents(".sticky").attr("id")); }
        }))
        )
        .append($("<span />", { 
            html : data.title, 
            contentEditable : true, 
            "class" : "sticky-title", 
            keypress : markUnsaved
        }))
    .append($("<div />", { 
        html : data.text, 
        contentEditable : true, 
        "class" : "sticky-content", 
        keypress : markUnsaved
    }))
    .draggable({ 
        handle : "div.sticky-header", 
        stack : ".sticky",
        start : markUnsaved,
        stop  : saveSticky  
    })
    .css({
        position: "absolute",
        "top" : data.top,
        "left": data.left
    })
    .focusout(saveSticky)
    .appendTo(document.body);
},
```

and here is the version that saves but isn't located correctly

```
var initStickies = function initStickies() {

    $("<div />", { 
        text : "+", 
        "class" : "add-sticky",
        click : function () { createSticky(); }
    }).prependTo(document.body);
    initStickies = null;
},
openStickies = function openStickies() {
    initStickies && initStickies();
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        try {
            createSticky(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))));

        } catch (error) { }
    }
},
createSticky = function createSticky(data) {
    data = data || { id : +new Date(), top : "40px", left : "40px", text : "Note Here", title : "Title" }
    return $("<div />", { 
        "class" : "sticky",
        'id' : data.id
    })

    .prepend($("<div />", { "class" : "sticky-header"} )
        .append($("<span />", { 
            html : data.title, 
            contentEditable : true, 
            "class" : "sticky-title", 
            keypress : markUnsaved
        }))
        .append($("<span />", { 
            "class" : "sticky-status", 
            click : saveSticky 
        }))
        .append($("<span />", { 
            "class" : "close-sticky", 
            text : "trash", 
            click : function () { deleteSticky($(this).parents(".sticky").attr("id")); }
        }))
        )

    .append($("<div />", { 
        html : data.text, 
        contentEditable : true, 
        "class" : "sticky-content", 
        keypress : markUnsaved
    }))
    .draggable({ 
        handle : "div.sticky-header", 
        stack : ".sticky",
        start : markUnsaved,
        stop  : saveSticky  
    })
    .css({
        position: "absolute",
        "top" : data.top,
        "left": data.left
    })
    .focusout(saveSticky)
    .appendTo(document.body);
},
deleteSticky = function deleteSticky(id) {
    localStorage.removeItem("sticky-" + id);
    $("#" + id).fadeOut(200, function () { $(this).remove(); });
},
saveSticky = function saveSticky() {
    var that = $(this),  sticky = (that.hasClass("sticky-status") || that.hasClass("sticky-title") || that.hasClass("sticky-content")) ? that.parents('div.sticky'): that,
    obj = {
        id  : sticky.attr("id"),
        top : sticky.css("top"),
        left: sticky.css("left"),
        text: sticky.children(".sticky-content").html(),
        title : sticky.children(".sticky-title").html() }
        localStorage.setItem("sticky-" + obj.id, JSON.stringify(obj));  
        sticky.find(".sticky-status").text("saved");
    },
    markUnsaved = function markUnsaved() {
        var that = $(this), sticky = that.hasClass("sticky-content") || that.hasClass("sticky-title") ? that.parents("div.sticky") : that;
        sticky.find(".sticky-status").text("unsaved");
    }
    return {
        open   : openStickies,
        init   : initStickies,
        "new"  : createSticky,
        remove : deleteSticky,
        save : saveSticky
    };
}());
```

And here's the localStorage code (var names are bad)

```
 var that = $(this),  sticky = (that.hasClass("sticky-status") || that.hasClass("sticky-title") || that.hasClass("sticky-content")) ? that.parents('div.sticky'): that,
    obj = {
        id  : sticky.attr("id"),
        top : sticky.css("top"),
        left: sticky.css("left"),
        text: sticky.children(".sticky-content").html(),
        title : sticky.children(".sticky-title").html() }
        localStorage.setItem("sticky-" + obj.id, JSON.stringify(obj));  
        sticky.find(".sticky-status").text("saved");
    },
    markUnsaved = function markUnsaved() {
        var that = $(this), sticky = that.hasClass("sticky-content") || that.hasClass("sticky-title") ? that.parents("div.sticky") : that;
        sticky.find(".sticky-status").text("unsaved");
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I'm not sure how to add multiple dependencies to a jsfiddle (json2.js, jquery, and jquery-ui)

Comment: Whatever you get it `data` you store it manually and I hope `json2.js` is not required here to demonstrate when you make it manual!! Other two you can add in fiddle!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using sticky.children to save which only works for the top child, changing it to 'sticky.find' worked perfectly